# Passing a table of varchar2 to a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need have a package with procedure accepting a parameter of type table of varchar2(255).

Package spec:

```
  type charArray is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;
```

Package body:

```
PROCEDURE call_me (p1 IN charArray, p2 IN VARCHAR2) IS ...
```

I tried calling this procedure using:

```
declare
    type t_type is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;

    l_array t_type;

begin

  l_array := ('131240');

  pkg._name.call_me (l_array, 'name');

end;
```

I'm getting this error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'call_me'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: l_array(1) := '131240';

dbms_output.put_line('-' || l_array(1));

this works, but how can I pass l_array to my procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You've got two types declared with the same definition, but that doesn't make them compatible. In order to pass the table into the package, you must use the type declared in the package:

```
declare
    l_array pkg_name.charArray;    
begin
    l_array(1) := '131240';
    pkg_name.call_me (l_array, 'name');
end;
```

Comment: Hi Brian, yes you are absolutely right, thanks for this. works like a dream :)